# Elements/tools in an SSIS package dont work when run by Windows task scheduler but work fine when run manually

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package to load data from multiple CSV files into an SQL staging table, then aggregate the rows of the staging table and insert those records into a destination table and finally delete the staging table rows.
The Package works fine when run manually.
When run using the windows task scheduler(using a .bat file), the package manages to load data from CSV into staging but doesn't do the aggregation ,insert and delete steps.
There are no errors seen in the Task scheduler post execution.
In the SSIS logs however, the following error was seen: *Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {32E37890-EC10-4F89-8D74-1B8CAA4C95F2} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly* .
I am not very savvy with the tool so wasn't able to understand what the error meant or how to resolve this.
I have not found the need to use any parameters in this package as the operations are quite straight forward and did not require any.

The .bat file contains

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "E:\Third Party Supply Performance\CNMA_DATA_EXTRACTION\CNMA_3RDPARTY_SUPPLY_DATA_EXTRACT\CNMA_3RDPARTY_SUPPLY_DATA_EXTRACT\CNMA_DATA_EXTRACTION.dtsx"
```

Could someone share some guidance on this issue or what I may be missing in terms of package design?

Comment: 1) Where does the data come from that the query is using? 2) What is the exact command you have in task scheduler/bat file 3) "when run manually" - what does that mean in this context? Run from Visual Studio? Double click the .bat file? Something else?

Comment: 1) the data consists of records loaded into the staging table from the CSV input files. 2) the .bat file contains this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "E:\Third Party Supply Performance\CNMA_DATA_EXTRACTION\CNMA_3RDPARTY_SUPPLY_DATA_EXTRACT\CNMA_3RDPARTY_SUPPLY_DATA_EXTRACT\CNMA_DATA_EXTRACTION.dtsx" . 3) "when run manually" yes, I meant that I ran the package through visual studio. I haven't tried to run it by double clicking the .bat file. Note: the task scheduler does manage to execute some of the components of the package (i.e. load data from CSV)

Comment: As a quick test, if you change the batch file to be `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe` does it work any better? This uses the 64 bit executable to run the package vs the 32/x86 version

Comment: Unfortunately, even the data load (from CSV files to staging) components failed to work after this change to the batch string. just for reference, I chose the 32 bit executable based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmQdF65S6X4 .

Comment: There ought to be more error messages available. If you modify your batch again, this time to redirect the run log to a file, what happens. Something like `...CNMA_DATA_EXTRACTION.dtsx /REP EIW > C:\temp\ssis_run_log.txt` assuming C:\temp exists and the account running the scheduled package has permissions there. That /REP option indicates we'd like to report on Errors, Information and Warning events.

Comment: I checked the log file that is configured to the SSIS package , but when running through the 64bit executable I'm able to observe that the log file remains undisturbed i.e. there are no traces of the execution logs written into it. Another observation was that while running the task with the 64bit .bat string, the execution history in the Task scheduler starts and ends almost instantly. whereas, when using the 32bit string, the Task scheduler takes ~1.5 minutes from the time the task starts till it indicates that the action is completed. Not sure if I am making sense.